# Run time error 1004: method "select of object_worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

After uploading the data in Excel file and running the macro code in it to publish the report, getting the

> Runtime error 1004 - Method "Select of Object"_Worksheet" Failed

```
        MailBCC = ""
        MailSubject = "Stack Ranking Result : " & Sheet3.Cells(EmployeeDetailRowNo, 2) & "(" & Sheet3.Cells(EmployeeDetailRowNo, 1) & ")"
        Sheet4.Select
        Sheet4.Range("A1").Select
        Sheet4.Range("C4").Value = Sheet2.Cells(StackRowNo, 1)
        Call SendingMail(MailTo, MailCC, MailBCC, Sheet4.Range("A1:I33"), MailSubject)

        StackRowNo = StackRowNo + 1
    Loop

    Sheet4.Select
    Sheet4.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for all of those instances of  `.Select`. This is a front-end feature and is rarely needed on the back-end

Comment: [How to avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: What line produces the error?  Do you have worksheets with  **CodeName**s `sheet3` and `sheet4`?

Comment: Sheet4.Select --- this line gets highlighted when we go in VB debugger

Comment: And do you have a worksheet with the **code name**  (**not** the sheet name on the tab) `sheet 4`?

Comment: no, i don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Take out all those `Selects` and it should work:

```
  MailBCC = ""
  MailSubject = "Stack Ranking Result : " & Sheet3.Cells(EmployeeDetailRowNo, 2) & _
  "(" & Sheet3.Cells(EmployeeDetailRowNo, 1) & ")"

  Sheet4.Range("C4").Value = Sheet2.Cells(StackRowNo, 1)
  Call SendingMail(MailTo, MailCC, MailBCC, Sheet4.Range("A1:I33"), MailSubject)

  StackRowNo = StackRowNo + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I'll leave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) here. You should definitely read it before doing further coding.